# How to update Password with new password on Reset Password

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, next.js

The **GITHUB REPO** i'm using [code repository](https://github.com/kaloraat/react-node-next-multi-user-blogging-platform/tree/master/115%20reset%20password%20backend/backend)

I'm trying to reset the user password on redirecting the user to reset password page. On the 1st Singup I'm hashing the password and salt is generated and stored in database using **[CRYPTO](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto)**. On reset password the new password is not getting updated it does not allow to signin using the updated password.
I tried using `response.password` which gives the updated password.Still couldn't figure out the solution.

Reset password :

```
 exports.resetPassword = (req,res) => {

    const {resetPasswordLink,  newPassword } = req.body

    if(resetPasswordLink){
            jwt.verify(resetPasswordLink,process.env.JWT_RESET_PASSWORD,  function(err,decoded){
                    if(err){
                        return res.status(401).json({
                            error : ' The Link has been expired ! , Try Again '
                        })
                    }

                    User.findOne({resetPasswordLink},(err,user)=>{
                        if(err || !user){
                            return res.status(401).json({
                                error: ' The Link has been expired ! , Try Again '
                            })
                        }

                        const updatedFields = {
                            password: newPassword,
                            resetPasswordLink: ''
                        }

                        user = _.extend(user,updatedFields)
                        user.save((err,result)=>{
                                if(err){
                                    return res.status(400).json({
                                        error: errorHandler(err)
                                    })
                                }
                                return res.json({
                                    message: ` Your Password Has Been Successfully Reset , Please Return to the SignIn Page to SignIn `
                                //    result.password
                             })
                        })
                    })
            }) 
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE 4th August :
Here's the complete USER model**

User Schema :

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        username: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            required: true,
            max: 32,
            unique: true,
            index: true,
            lowercase: true
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            required: true,
            max: 32
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
            lowercase: true
        },
        profile: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        hashed_password: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        salt: String,
        about: {
            type: String
        },
        role: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        photo: {
            data: Buffer,
            contentType: String
        },
        resetPasswordLink: {
            data: String,
            default: ''
        }
    },
    { timestamp: true }
);

userSchema
    .virtual('password')
    .set(function(password) {
        // create a temporarity variable called _password
        this._password = password;
        // generate salt
        this.salt = this.makeSalt();
        // encryptPassword
        this.hashed_password = this.encryptPassword(password);
    })
    .get(function() {
        return this._password;
    });

userSchema.methods = {
    authenticate: function(plainText) {
        return this.encryptPassword(plainText) === this.hashed_password;
    },

    encryptPassword: function(password) {
        if (!password) return '';
        try {
            return crypto
                .createHmac('sha1', this.salt)
                .update(password)
                .digest('hex');
        } catch (err) {
            return '';
        }
    },

    makeSalt: function() {
        return Math.round(new Date().valueOf() * Math.random()) + '';
    }
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Comment: May be problem is in your signin function where you have set expiry of 'jwt' and 'cookie' use { expiresIn: '1d' } instead of { expiresIn: '1' } because '1' means your jwt and cookie expires in 1 ms

Comment: I tried with { expiresIn : '2d' } , still gives me the same error.
[updated github repo](https://github.com/kaloraat/react-node-next-multi-user-blogging-platform/blob/master/124%20static%20home%20page/backend/controllers/auth.js)

Comment: The problem might be with the Reset password Controller method , While signing up a user you are hashing the password , but for resetting the password you are not doing the same, Try hashing the reset password too.

Comment: @Nitin there is no need to hash reset password because user model contain setter on 'password' virtual property.when user.save() call from resetPassword Controller  method it will call setter of password and store hashed password for new password

Comment: I have updated the question , Please have a look @DimplePatel

Comment: Use findOneAndUpdate instead of findOne in your query

Comment: @jarivak I have taken backend code folder from your Git repo mentioned in first line of question and made just one change that I’ve mentioned in my earlier comment {expiresIn:’1d’}.After that I run my code and check backend code using postman and all functionality working fine, new password updated correctly and allow us to login using new password so  there is no need to change anything on backend side.So,I recommend you that instead of just focusing on backend debug your frontend code and make sure that correct resetPasswordLink is passed to resetpassword controller from frontend

Comment: @DimplePatel thanks :) it's working perfectly now , I guess i had a typo or something but now its working fine , I changed {expiresIn : '1d' } .
Could you please post it as answer ? The question has a bounty started along with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem is in your signin function where you have set expiry of 'jwt' and 'cookie' use { expiresIn: '1d' } instead of { expiresIn: '1' } because '1' means your jwt and cookie expires in 1 ms

```
 const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '1d' });
 res.cookie('token', token, { expiresIn: '1d' });
```